# Who or what is the captain of the temple mentioned in acts 4:& 5

Tags: acts

Acts 4:1 (KJV)

> And as they spake unto the people, the priests, and the ***captain of the temple***, and the Sadducees, came upon them, 2 Being grieved that they taught the people, and preached through Jesus the resurrection from the dead.

Acts 5:24 (KJV)

> 24 Now when the high priest and the ***captain of the temple*** and the chief priests heard these things, they doubted of them whereunto this would grow.

Who is this captain mentioned in tandem with the priests & what exactly was his role in the temple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The Talmud provides the most information about the captain of the temple, but it is still scanty. In the Kodashim, [Middoth](https://halakhah.com/pdf/kodoshim/Middoth.pdf), ch. I, pp. 1-5, this man, “the officer of the temple mount,” is said to be in charge of twenty-four watches, or guard posts, located at important spots about the Temple courtyard. In [Tamid](https://halakhah.com/pdf/kodoshim/Tamid.pdf), ch. I, pp. 1-12, it is said that this officer, second to the high priest, was in charge of three groups of priests who guarded the Chamber of Abtimas, the Chamber of the Spark, and the Chamber of Fire. In addition he commanded twenty-one groups of Levites who were placed elsewhere, particularly at the five gates.<sup>1</sup>

<sub>1 https://www.biblegateway.com/resources/encyclopedia-of-the-bible/Captain-Temple or https://www.biblicaltraining.org/library/captain-temple</sub>